# Can't save emacs config file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

After using `C-x C-s` I see

> indenting region done.

in the minibuffer and all my changes are not saved.

Comment: Without further info it's hard to tell, what's wrong. Any messages in the *Messages* buffer? You can use `M-x save-buffer` to save your file.

Comment: Did you customize any emacs config file? Did you install any add-ons? Do you have any keyboard macros defined anywhere? Did you just install emacs, or did it work earlier? OS and emacs versions?

Comment: `C-h k C-x C-s` will at least tell you whether that binding has been clobbered by something else.

Answer (score 3):

My crystal ball tells me you have something like

```
(add-hook 'write-file-functions <something-that-reindents-buffer>)
```

somewhere in your `~/.emacs`.  `write-file-functions` is a hook to let you change the way something is written, but it's often been abused to just do something before writing the file.

A function on `write-file-functions` should indicate whether it did write the file or not, by returning either nil or non-nil, and my crystal ball thinks that `<something-that-reindents-buffer>` happens to return a non-nil value.

If my crystal ball got it right, the fix would be to use `before-save-hook` instead.